# How to select a fixed value using Arel?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, arel

I'd like to add an extra column to an [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel) select result, where the value in the column is the same on every row, so that I can add extra information about the context of the query to a Rails ActiveRecord object.

So, how would I generate this SQL using Arel?

```
select date('2013-12-25') as foo
```

It should result in a result with a single column and a single row which contains a date value. I've used MySQL syntax here, but I'd like it to generate correct SQL for whichever backend is being used.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the answer is:

```
include Arel
select = SelectManager.new(Table.engine)
select.project(Nodes::NamedFunction.new('date', ['2013-12-25']).as('foo'))
select.to_sql
```